# Transferring files from remote Mac SSH to school Linux Server

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, connection

This is the first thing computer science related that I have ever done.

I am remotely connected to my school's Linux server via the terminal.

```
ssh username@school.com
```

I fill in the password and connect just fine. I can make directories and everything.

I have looked up a few posts on how to transfer files from the Mac that I am using to the Linux server, and they involve using scp command. I cannot seem to get this to work, and am unsure which IP addresses I should be inputting.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like how you ssh

```
ssh user@school.com
```

then you just use this to copy file.ext from your computer

```
scp file.ext user@school.com:/path/where/you/want/to/put/
```

Googling first there are a lot of this information. And remember that the path where you want to put the file must be writable for the user, for example in home directory such as /home/user

The output is something like this:

```
scp file.ext user@school.com:/home/user/
user@school.com's password:
```

For an easy approach use sftp manager like Filezilla or anyother manager and choose port 22, which is sftp (ftp via secure). It's much more easy because it is GUI, so you can use mouse to drag and drop the file.

Comment: I am trying the first method first, and will attempt the latter if I cannot figure it out. It gives me the following message when I do the scp: Enter passphrase for key '/home/2015/username/.ssh/id_rsa': I tried to enter my ssh password and it did not work. EDIT: The Filezilla worked, you are my hero.

Comment: @Winter, that should be the same password you use when ssh'ing your remote computer.